# Trigger method defined in javascript object, but outside of the object itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I suspect my question may be a bit obtuse, and I apologize. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I am using this [multi-level push menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/), and it works fine out of the box. However, I would like the multi-level menu to close after a modal is submitted and closed. I am having a difficult time figuring out how to trigger this menu to close.

So, on to some code. Up first, the Javascript that runs the menu itself.

```
mlPushMenu.prototype = {
    defaults : {
        // overlap: there will be a gap between open levels
        // cover: the open levels will be on top of any previous open level
        type : 'overlap', // overlap || cover
        // space between each overlaped level
        levelSpacing : 40,
        // classname for the element (if any) that when clicked closes the current level
        backClass : 'mp-back'
    },
    _init : function() {
        // if menu is open or not
        this.open = false;
        // level depth
        this.level = 0;
        // the moving wrapper
        this.wrapper = document.getElementById( 'mp-pusher' );
        // the mp-level elements
        this.levels = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'div.mp-level' ) );
        // save the depth of each of these mp-level elements
        var self = this;
        this.levels.forEach( function( el, i ) { el.setAttribute( 'data-level', getLevelDepth( el, self.el.id, 'mp-level' ) ); } );
        // the menu items
        this.menuItems = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'li' ) );
        // if type == "cover" these will serve as hooks to move back to the previous level
        this.levelBack = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.' + this.options.backClass ) );
        // event type (if mobile use touch events)
        this.eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
        // add the class mp-overlap or mp-cover to the main element depending on options.type
        classie.add( this.el, 'mp-' + this.options.type );
        // initialize / bind the necessary events
        this._initEvents();
    },
    _initEvents : function() {
        var self = this;

        // the menu should close if clicking somewhere on the body
        var bodyClickFn = function( el ) {
            self._resetMenu();
            el.removeEventListener( self.eventtype, bodyClickFn );
        };

        // open (or close) the menu
        this.trigger.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function( ev ) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            if( self.open ) {
                self._resetMenu();
            }
            else {
                self._openMenu();
                // the menu should close if clicking somewhere on the body (excluding clicks on the menu)
                document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                    if( self.open && !hasParent( ev.target, self.el.id ) ) {
                        bodyClickFn( this );
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );

        // opening a sub level menu
        this.menuItems.forEach( function( el, i ) {
            // check if it has a sub level
            var subLevel = el.querySelector( 'div.mp-level' );
            if( subLevel ) {
                el.querySelector( 'a' ).addEventListener( self.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    var level = closest( el, 'mp-level' ).getAttribute( 'data-level' );
                    if( self.level <= level ) {
                        ev.stopPropagation();
                        classie.add( closest( el, 'mp-level' ), 'mp-level-overlay' );
                        self._openMenu( subLevel );
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );

        // closing the sub levels :
        // by clicking on the visible part of the level element
        this.levels.forEach( function( el, i ) {
            el.addEventListener( self.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                var level = el.getAttribute( 'data-level' );
                if( self.level > level ) {
                    self.level = level;
                    self._closeMenu();
                }
            } );
        } );

        // by clicking on a specific element
        this.levelBack.forEach( function( el, i ) {
            el.addEventListener( self.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var level = closest( el, 'mp-level' ).getAttribute( 'data-level' );
                if( self.level <= level ) {
                    ev.stopPropagation();
                    self.level = closest( el, 'mp-level' ).getAttribute( 'data-level' ) - 1;
                    self.level === 0 ? self._resetMenu() : self._closeMenu();
                }
            } );
        } );    
    },
    _openMenu : function( subLevel ) {
        // increment level depth
        ++this.level;

        // move the main wrapper
        var levelFactor = ( this.level - 1 ) * this.options.levelSpacing,
            translateVal = this.options.type === 'overlap' ? this.el.offsetWidth + levelFactor : this.el.offsetWidth;

        this._setTransform( 'translate3d(' + translateVal + 'px,0,0)' );

        if( subLevel ) {
            // reset transform for sublevel
            this._setTransform( '', subLevel );
            // need to reset the translate value for the level menus that have the same level depth and are not open
            for( var i = 0, len = this.levels.length; i < len; ++i ) {
                var levelEl = this.levels[i];
                if( levelEl != subLevel && !classie.has( levelEl, 'mp-level-open' ) ) {
                    this._setTransform( 'translate3d(-100%,0,0) translate3d(' + -1*levelFactor + 'px,0,0)', levelEl );
                }
            }
        }
        // add class mp-pushed to main wrapper if opening the first time
        if( this.level === 1 ) {
            classie.add( this.wrapper, 'mp-pushed' );
            this.open = true;
        }
        // add class mp-level-open to the opening level element
        classie.add( subLevel || this.levels[0], 'mp-level-open' );
    },
    // close the menu
    _resetMenu : function() {
        this._setTransform('translate3d(0,0,0)');
        this.level = 0;
        // remove class mp-pushed from main wrapper
        classie.remove( this.wrapper, 'mp-pushed' );
        this._toggleLevels();
        this.open = false;
    },
    // close sub menus
    _closeMenu : function() {
        var translateVal = this.options.type === 'overlap' ? this.el.offsetWidth + ( this.level - 1 ) * this.options.levelSpacing : this.el.offsetWidth;
        this._setTransform( 'translate3d(' + translateVal + 'px,0,0)' );
        this._toggleLevels();
    },
    // translate the el
    _setTransform : function( val, el ) {
        el = el || this.wrapper;
        el.style.WebkitTransform = val;
        el.style.MozTransform = val;
        el.style.transform = val;
    },
    // removes classes mp-level-open from closing levels
    _toggleLevels : function() {
        for( var i = 0, len = this.levels.length; i < len; ++i ) {
            var levelEl = this.levels[i];
            if( levelEl.getAttribute( 'data-level' ) >= this.level + 1 ) {
                classie.remove( levelEl, 'mp-level-open' );
                classie.remove( levelEl, 'mp-level-overlay' );
            }
            else if( Number( levelEl.getAttribute( 'data-level' ) ) == this.level ) {
                classie.remove( levelEl, 'mp-level-overlay' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method I would like to invoke would be _resetMenu. I have tried this a couple of ways. The primary was trying to trigger the click event of the button that opens the menu:

```
<a href="#" id="trigger" class="show-root-menu"><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i></a>
```

However:

```
$('#trigger').trigger('click');
```

does not work as expected. I would expect this to be fired:

```
// open (or close) the menu
        this.trigger.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function( ev ) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            if( self.open ) {
                self._resetMenu();
            }
            else {
                self._openMenu();
                // the menu should close if clicking somewhere on the body (excluding clicks on the menu)
                document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                    if( self.open && !hasParent( ev.target, self.el.id ) ) {
                        bodyClickFn( this );
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );
```

In this case, `this.eventtype` is 'click'.

I suspect this may have something to do with how this functionality is coded with an object. While I have decent Javascript skills, I have not had much exposure to using it in this manner.

I am instantiating the menu thusly:

```
new mlPushMenu(document.getElementById('mp-menu'), document.getElementById('trigger'));
```

I realize I could extract this method, but that seems to violate some best practices in general.

Any suggestions will be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use this module as-is to do this. The only event types it supports are "click" and "touchstart" and its `mobilecheck()` method determines which one of the two it uses.

You'll either have to fake a click on a trigger element or you'll have to modify this module. You can do this with the `.click()` method of a DOM element. `.trigger.click()` probably won't do it; you would probably be better off just getting the element (via `$('#trigger')` or `document.getElementById()`) and then calling the .click() method of that.

I just tried this in Chrome with an `<a>` with style `display:none` and it followed the link so it may work for another hidden element set to trigger. It's hacky but it might be preferable to changing the module.

Comment: Ok. As silly as it seems to me, `document.getElementById('trigger').click();` worked. Not sure why the jQuery route failed, but thank you Ryan!